# How do I import 3ds models into JAVAFX?

Tags: javafx-2, 3ds

Here are the loaders, but I can't find an example of how to use the code on the internet. I have plenty of models as I'm a 3d modeler, but I don't know how to use the following link to import my 3ds models into javafx. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html

Answer (score 3):

Use the [InteractiveMesh 3D Model Browser](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dbrowser.html) to load your model.

This will allow you to check that the 3D Model Importer and JavaFX 3D are capable of loading and rendering your 3ds model.  This is a worthwhile check as both the 3D model importer and the JavaFX 3D API are currently early access releases which may have some issues or limitations displaying your particular models.

If the model browser application works with your models and you want to import the 3ds models into your own program, you could adapt a variation the answer to: [How to create 3d shape from STL in JavaFX 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462571/how-to-create-3d-shape-from-stl-in-javafx-8)  As that answer deals with STL files, to import a 3ds file, substitute the `TdsModelImporter` for the STL importer.  The rest of the test harness code remains the same (making appropriate adjustments for lighting, model scale, etc).

The [interactive mesh model importer download](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/download/JFX3DModelImporters_EA_2013-12-27.zip) includes api javadoc on usage of the `TdsModelImporter` for 3ds models.

For further questions, I advise you to contact [InteractiveMesh](http://www.interactivemesh.org/impressum.html) directly.

[image: javadoc]

Answer (score 2):

To use the InteractiveMesh 3D Model Browser to load your 3Ds model.

```
ModelImporter tdsImporter = new TdsModelImporter();
tdsImporter.read(fileUrl);
Node[] tdsMesh = (Node[]) tdsImporter.getImport();
tdsImporter.close();
```