# Import STL file in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafx-3d, stl-format

My problem is that I am trying to import a 3D model from an STL file to a JavaFX application. I followed the code in this link [How to create 3d shape from STL in JavaFX 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462571/how-to-create-3d-shape-from-stl-in-javafx-8?answertab=oldest#tab-top) and it's only working with the jewel file mentioned there, but I've tried with other STL files and it's not working!

I can't see why it's not working with the other files. Can anyone explain this?
Any help please, as soon as possible!

Comment: STL tag is referenced for C++ Standard Template Library. IMHO STL here has nothing to do with this tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are already using an STL importer from this [site](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html), you will find in the same web a [3D model browser](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dbrowser.html) you can use to preview your models before importing them to your JavaFX application.

If they can't be imported with this browser, the problem may be related to a non valid STL format in your files.

If they are imported, then the problem may be in your application. Embed the call in a try-catch and post the exception you may enconter.

```
StlMeshImporter stlImporter = new StlMeshImporter(); 

try {
    stlImporter.read(this.getClass().getResource("<STLfile>.stl"));
}
catch (ImportException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

**EDIT**

If no exception is thrown while reading the model, the next step would be inserting the returned mesh into a `MeshView` and show it on our scene:

```
TriangleMesh mesh = stlImporter.getImport();
stlImporter.close();
MeshView mesh=new MeshView(cylinderHeadMesh);
Group root = new Group(mesh);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 800, true);
Camera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
scene.setCamera(camera);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Since the model could be too small or too big for our scene (related to the camera and the point of view we are using), we should print the bounding box of our model, and then scale it up or down accordingly:

```
System.out.println("mesh: "+mesh.getBoundsInLocal().toString());
mesh.setScaleX(1d);
mesh.setScaleY(1d);
mesh.setScaleZ(1d);
```

Or we could change the camera parameters:

```
double max = Math.max(mesh.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth(),
              Math.max(mesh.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight(),
                       mesh.getBoundsInLocal().getDepth()));
camera.setTranslateZ(-3*max);
```

Comment: I've already previewed them in the browser and there is nothing wrong with the files. I don't really know where is the problem in the application, the try-catch is not helpful because the import passes..