# Add 3D models to JavaFX group

Tags: javafx, 3d

In javaFX I can create rectangle/circles... and other 2D geometric figures.
In the Group i can add them with:

```
group.getChildren().add("Name");
```

Also I can check collision:

```
hero = character.localToScene(character.getBoundsInLocal());
yewTree = yew.localToScene( yew.getBoundsInLocal());        

                if ( yewTree.intersects(hero) )
                {

                }
```

... and perform action if it happens.

There is another amazing thing: 
AnimationTimer and TranslateTransition. It not only lets me to do periodic/continous animation, but also it checks some states.
( I can make few game loops without making major game loop, as they works independend. )

**AND THE QUESTION COMES.**

Can I add 3d models ( stl, obj, 3ds...) to the group and manimulate them ( scaling, changing coordinates, check collision, use them as a node in animation timer or Translatetransition )?

Im not sure about http://www.interactivemesh.org/
. I expect there is some kind of alternative, as it is confusing, lack of documentation, few examples on the Internet I found - do not works.

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37516327/230513).

Comment: This example do not works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462571/how-to-create-3d-shape-from-stl-in-javafx-8

Comment: Tested with Java version 1.8.0_144.